# Save as to GMT in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gmt

I have a problem with saving as GMT in QGIS. There is no option in my QGIS version to save as in GMT. How I can add this option in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

In the OSGEO4W shell, run `ogr2ogr --formats|sort` to see if you have the `OGR_GMT` driver (running GDAL 2.x) or `GMT` driver (running GDAL 1.x) included.

If yes, you can convert your **vector** data with `ogr2ogr -of OGR_GMT` or `-of GMT`.

If you have **raster** data, run `gdalinfo --formats|sort` to look for the `GMT` driver, then take `gdal_translate -of GMT`.

Answer (score 2):

This same question was asked, and answered, in the GMT forum
https://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/boards/1/topics/8087?r=8088#message-8088

-Regarding the raster matter, it's not advised to convert grids into the old GMT netcdf grid format. Just don't convert it. GMT can recognized all GDAL formats natively (it uses GDAL to read them).